# An example of a vertex-critical graph which is not edge-critial

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

$\chi(G)$ ( vertex-chromatic number of a graph like $G$) is the minimum number of colors which is enough to color every vertex of $G$ such that no two adjacent vertices have the same color.

A graph like G is called k-vertex-critical if $\chi(G)=k$ and for each $v \in V(G)\space\space\space\space\chi(G-v) \lt \chi(G)$  .

$\chi'(G)$ ( edge-chromatic number of a graph like $G$) is the minimum number of colors which is enough to color every edge of $G$ such that no two edges of the same color share a common vertex.

A graph like G is called k-edge-critical if $\chi'(G)=k$ and for each $e \in E(G)\space\space\space\space\chi'(G-e) \lt \chi'(G)$  .

Now the question :
Can you find a vertex-critical graph which is not edge-critical?

Note:  **I don't want** a graph with critical vertices and without critical edges. This question is different. Here, we deal with every edge and every vertex not just one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K_4$ would be an example.

A proper vertex-coloring requires 4 colors, and $K_4-v=K_3$ requires only 3 colors, so $K_4$ is vertex critical.

A proper edge-coloring requires 3 colors (verify!), but $K_4-e$ still has a triangle, so $K_4-e$ still requires 3 colors, so $K_4$ is not edge-critical.

EDIT: $K_{2n}$ is an example for any $n\geq2$.
It is obviously vertex-critical. A proper edge-coloring requires $2n-1$ colors (verify!), but $K_{2n}-e$ still requires $2n-1$ colors, since it has maximum degree $2n-1$, so $K_{2n}$ is not edge-critical.

Comment: It seems that your answer is correct ... but i want a more complicated example...

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade: please define "complicated".

Comment: our teacher told us that this graph has 8 or 9 vertices

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade: see edit, you now have an infinite number of examples, one of them has 8 vertices.